# how to get definition of a function in python?

Tags: python, function

I have a function mentioned below in python:

```
>>> students=[]

>>> def add_student(name):
...     students.append(name)
```

How can i get actual text of add_student?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the definition"?

Comment: Do you want the actual text of the `add_student` function?

Comment: Do you want to return the source code?

Comment: In worst case (i.e. when the function is native) the only thing you can get is the signature. If the function is pure Python then you can retrieve its bytecode, but I don't see how is that useful to be honest.

Comment: if you use IPython or Jupyter, use

    ??add_student

Comment: @ShpielMeister - I am using IDLE python 3.5

Comment: @BrendanAbel - Yes.

Comment: This question should be re-opened, as the linked duplicate only works for functions created from a source file, not on functions created in an interactive prompt.

Comment: @BrendanAbel Really?! Did you actually ***read*** the answers? I did and found **three** interactive prompt answers, [one](//stackoverflow.com/a/17358307), [two](//stackoverflow.com/a/21339166) and [three](//stackoverflow.com/a/25107178).